# VbScript Error Object Cleared by On Error Statement

Tags: vbscript, error-handling

Kind of a novice with VbScript, and trying to implement error handling.  My method is to pass the error object to a HandleErr sub, but the error apparently gets cleared by the "On Error Resume Next" statement withing the sub.  Using Windows 7.

```
On Error Resume Next
Dim x
x = 1/0
msgbox "Original Error: " & err.Number & " - " & err.Description
if err.number <> 0 then HandleErr err

Sub HandleErr(objErr)
    on error resume next  '### Without this On Error statement, the script runs fine.
    msgbox "Error in HandleErr: " & objErr.Number & " - " & objErr.Description '### objErr.Number becomes zero.
    WScript.Quit objErr.Number
End Sub
```

I imagine there is a simple answer for this.  Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Use `On Error Goto 0` to disable `On Error Resume Next` and `Err.Clear()` to clear the current error once you've trapped it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You want to stop the skipping errors with `On Error Resume Next` once you reach `HandleErr()`. Also use `Err.Clear()` to reset `Err` object.

```vb
On Error Resume Next
Dim x
x = 1/0
MsgBox "Original Error: " & Err.Number & " - " & Err.Description
if Err.Number <> 0 then HandleErr Err
'Stop skipping lines when errors occur.
On Error Goto 0

Sub HandleErr(objErr)
    MsgBox "Error in HandleErr: " & objErr.Number & " - " & objErr.Description '### objErr.Number becomes zero.
    'Clear current error now you have trapped it.
    Err.Clear
    WScript.Quit objErr.Number
End Sub
```

Personally though I wouldn't pass `Err` into your function because `Err` is a global built-in object so you can still check the values without passing it in.

```vb
On Error Resume Next
Dim x
x = 1/0
MsgBox "Original Error: " & Err.Number & " - " & Err.Description
Call HandleErr()
'Stop skipping lines when errors occur.
On Error Goto 0

Sub HandleErr()
    'Do we need to trap an error?
    If Err.Number <> 0 Then
        MsgBox "Error in HandleErr: " & Err.Number & " - " & Err.Description '### Err.Number becomes zero.
        'Clear current error now you have trapped it.
        Err.Clear
        WScript.Quit Err.Number
    End If
End Sub
```

Comment: Appreciate your answer.  I can see I wasn't completely clear.  The Msgbox within `HandleErr` is just for debugging.  I want this script to return the error code, so I don't necessarily want to clear the error.  From your code, I assume you are saying that an `On Error Resume Next` statement is unnecessary in the error handler?

Comment: Also, why put an `On Error Goto 0` on the last line of the script main body?

Comment: I completely see your point about not passing `Err` into the function.  I had tested to see if `Err` was really global, but my sub had an `On Error Resume Next` statement at the beginning.  This seems to clear the error.  Now I see that (without the `On Error`) you can access `Err` from the sub.

Comment: @JBStovers I'm confused as to what you are trying to do then. The `On Error Goto 0` at the end was to reset the error handling behaviour for other code you may have *(assumed this was just a snippet)*. Same with the `Err.Clear()`. Are you just asking why does `Err` get reset when you set `On Error Resume Next`, short answer...because it's designed to. Calling `On Error Resume Next` in that error handling function makes no sense, you are telling VBScript to skip any lines that contain errors and set the `Err` object to that error. Do you see why I'm confused?

Comment: If I was an experienced scripter, I'm sure I would understand your confusion! :) Since I am not, it seems reasonable to me that you could put `On Error Resume Next` in a sub, and an error generated in the main body would still exist. I guess it doesn't work that way, and you have to trap errors in the main body where they occur.

Comment: As for the `On Error Goto 0` statement, my normal practice is to put `On Error Resume Next` at the beginning, and evaluating `Err.Number` wherever it is likely an error will occur, then handle the error with `HandleErr`.